# How do I test authlogic in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authlogic

I can't get my tests to work and was wondering if anyone have any pointers. I am testing my user edit page such that you have to be logged in to be able to see and edit the user profile. Following the authlogic documentation, here are the relevant codes:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

  private

def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
end

def require_current_user
  unless current_user
    flash[:error] = 'You must be logged in'
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  end
end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_current_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  ...
end
```

## In my users_controller_spec

```
describe "GET 'edit'" do

        before(:each) do
            @user = Factory(:user)
            UserSession.create(@user)
        end     

        it "should be successful" do
            # test for /users/id/edit
            get :edit, :id => @user.id
            response.should be_success
        end
```

I tested it using the browser and it works. You have to be logged in to be able to edit your profile but it doesn't work in my rspec test.

I have a feeling it has something to do with [mock controller](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/TestCase/MockController#session-instance_method) but I can't figure out how. I've also read the [test case](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/TestCase#controller-instance_method) but still can't get it to work.

Please help and much thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub the current_user method on the ApplicationController like so:

```
fake_user = controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user) #you could use a let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } instead of before_each
get :edit, :id => fake_user.id
response.should be_success
```